# Calculate the weigths of a quadrature with highest precision

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

How do I calculate the weights $H_0$ and $H_1$ so that the the precision of the approximated function is as high as possible?
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\, dx \approx H_0 f\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) + H_1 f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: We know that $$ \int_{-1}^1 x^k\,dx = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } k\textrm{ is odd} \\
\frac{2}{k+1} & \mbox{if } k\textrm{ is even} \end{cases}  $$
when $k\geq 0$. Also, apply the quadrature method to $x^k$ and find $$ H_0\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k + H_1\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k. $$ 
Now you can generate equations for $H_0$ and $H_1$ for different values of $k$.